# Khan academy Scratchpad api

Tags: khan-academy

I want to scrape the Scratchpad from Khan academy but I don't know how to use the Scratchpad API.

I tried using articles and videos but it doesn't work.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take some time to review the [tour] and [ask]. Provide a [mcve] and add any relevant details around what is not working as expected.

Comment: Please specify what exactly you have tried so far codewise and where you have difficulties.

Comment: I find the API for the videos or articles is https://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/api/v1/topic/<topic_slug>/videos and http://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/articles/id but i don't find any documet which mention about Scratchpad

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Khan Academy scratchpad API by using JSON. For example, to get the amount of votes in a program, you can use JSON like this:

```
$.getJSON("https://www.khanacademy.org/api/labs/scratchpads/" + programID + "&callback=?", function(data) {
    console.log(data.sumVotesIncremented);
});
```

You can see what data you can collect here:

https://www.khanacademy.org/api/labs/scratchpads/6693037677641728 (or another id)

Answer (score 0):

Correct Answer:
Khan Academy API is now deprecated and you can no longer use it.